# Using the url package to update a channel on ThingSpeak

Tags: go, http-post, raspberry-pi

I am using the following part of code on a Raspberry Pi in order to continuously upload sampled [temperature & humidity] values onto a channel at ThingSpeak [https://www.thingspeak.com/]. The problem is that only the first value gets uploaded while the rest are ignored. What am i doing wrong? values.Set creates a not-previously created key, assigns to it a first value and replaces every next value without any problem. Why don't they get uploaded? Is there anything wrong with http.PostForm?

```
//imports

type Data struct {
    Temperature int
    Humidity    int
}

//....

var data Data

func httpPost(values url.Values) {
    values.Set("field1", fmt.Sprint(data.Temperature))
    values.Set("field2", fmt.Sprint(data.Humidity))
    log.Println(values)

    _, err := http.PostForm("http://api.thingspeak.com/update", values)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error posting values to thingspeak: %s", err)
    }
    return
}

//....

func main() {
    dataPool := []Data{{28, 41}, {24, 43}, {27, 42}, {21, 40}}
    values := make(url.Values)
    values.Set("key", "Write API Key")

    for _, value := range dataPool {
        data = value

        //ThingSpeak update
        httpPost(values)

        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    } 
}
```

I don't know much off networks but right now i am accessing internet via an Ethernet port that connects on a hub-based satellite internet connection [i guess not a normal router connection?] so maybe it's a administrative problem [dormitories, duh]. I should ask my network administrator about that but in any case i am putting this out here. Any feedback are welcome.

Comment: Since the logged values look right (your sample with the network call commented out is at http://play.golang.org/p/Ct1-oKXfCl), I am suspicious that maybe your code is posting the data as it should but ThingSpeak still somehow doesn't successfully process the requests. You could try logging ThingSpeak's replies to see if they contain anything informative, or making a couple of reqs by hand and seeing if that works.

Comment: After glancing at [`PostForm`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go#L378) and the code it calls, I'm almost sure it's is synchronous enough that `values` is read before it returns. But if it wasn't, and you had really bad latency to ThingSpeak, then it could possibly end up posting only the last set of values, since you keep updating a single `Values` with new data. If you happen to get different results by "manually" posting a couple of of handmade `url.Values` instances, you could try creating a new `Values` in each loop iteration. But I honestly doubt that's the problem.

Comment: The fact that you're on a satellite link will probably mean that you *do* have high network latency, as suggested by @user2714852 . I've also found that curl can provide *really* good feedback when testing HTTP APIs. Try sending the `POST` data with `time curl --verbose --data "field1=28&field2=41"` . This should tell you how long the post takes, as well as showing any returned errors from the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found what the problem was. Apparently ThingSpeak has an API Rate Limit of 15 seconds (http://community.thingspeak.com/documentation/api/) while i was trying to post on the channel every 2 seconds. I set 2 to 20 and everything works like a charm now. Thanks for your comments.

Moral lesson: next time read the documentation thoroughly:)